# Prohibit updating props of already rendered component in ListView

Tags: react-native

I have a `ListView` inside a component on which `setState` is sometimes called quite soon after scene load and in this set state I pass a new array for data source which I similar to the previous one but prepended with one element. So react rerenders the `ListView` but the problem is that it does this via cascade update of props or rows. Here's the illustration:

I had a list view:

```
<Component someProp=B /> // instance ID 1
<Component someProp=C /> // instance ID 2
<Component someProp=D /> // instance ID 3
```

Here instance ID is some ID of constructed component, which I show for reference. Now after I prepend the data with object having prop A, this happens to the list view:

```
<Component someProp=A /> // instance ID 1
<Component someProp=B /> // instance ID 2
<Component someProp=C /> // instance ID 3
<Component someProp=D /> // instance ID 4
```

As you can see, react created new component instance, but for last element (prop D), and previous elements were all updated triggering `componentWillReceiveProps`. Instance 1 was given prop A instead of B, and so on.

But here's the problem: on construction of row components I immediately run code, which synchronizes the component with remote server, something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    title: props.someProp,
    data: getCachedData(props.someProp)
  }
  RemoteServer.getFreshData(props.someProp)
    .then(data => this.setState({data}))
}
```

So this creates a bad situation: when fetch from remote server completes, this component might have already received new someProp, so the fresh data is pushed into wrong component instance. Of course I can request fresh data again in `componentWillReceiveProps`, but that is too much overhead.

Is there a way to tell react that my component should not receive new props when already constructed? So that it creates new component before others instead of updating props of all of them. Or is there another way to solve my problem?

Comment: can you show `componentWillReceiveProps`? Are you doing an async fetch in there too or just the constructor?

Comment: @FuzzyTree I am doing both async and sync fetch there too, yes, but of another data.

Answer (score 0):

in this way it will diff the data list to decide to re-render or not

```
 import {ListView} from react-native'
 const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

 //first concat old data with the new one
 let concatedData = this.state.dataSource.concat(newData);

 //then call this to update the listview
 this.setState({
     dataSource:ds.cloneWithRows(concatedData)
   });
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way I am doing update now except I am not appending, but prepending `newData`.